# Making sense of a package with almost no files included

Tags: package-management, opencv

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 4.19.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1 (2019-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need to use `cv::face::createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`, which is not a part of the core OpenCV but rather a contributed module.

```
$ dpkg -l libopencv-contrib-dev
ii  libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 3.2.0+dfsg-6 amd64        development files for libopencv-contrib3.2
```

everything fine ... no:

```
 src/cmd.cpp:150: error: ‘cv::face’ has not been declared
 const auto model = cv::face::createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
                        ^~~~
```

OK. Let's then include the needed headers manually:

```
$ dpkg -S libopencv-contrib-dev
libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib-dev
libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib-dev/copyright
libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64: /usr/share/doc/libopencv-contrib-dev/README.Debian
```

Nothing! Is this a packager's mistake (this is Debian **testing** after all)? An OpenCV peculiarity? A minor oversight on my side? I would like to continue using the package manager, instead of compiling the whole thing myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is fine, you’re using the wrong `dpkg` option:

```
dpkg -L libopencv-contrib-dev
```

will list all the files in the `libopencv-contrib-dev`, which is what you’re after (and will show all the files [listed here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libopencv-contrib-dev/filelist)), whereas

```
dpkg -S libopencv-contrib-dev
```

searches all installed packages for files with `libopencv-contrib-dev` in their path, which only matches the four files you’ve listed.

Answer (score 1):

It was an oversight on my part.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
```

The first include is insufficient, the second one is needed as well.

Although this solves the problem, I would appreciate an explaination why don't any useful files show up in `dpkg -S`.